# Why is a pyautogui script not executed in the background using dart's Process.run()?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, pyautogui

**Edit:** Problem Fixed. Just needed to replace "**python3**" with "**python3.9**" in my flutter code.

---

I have a pyautogui script. I have made a flutter app in which I have a button. When the button is pressed, the python script is executed in the background. What I can't understand at all is that the pyautogui part does not work. It works when I manually type "python3 <script.py>" in the terminal but not in Flutter.

---

And I am **100% sure** that my python script is executed because I ran a "print" command in one script and tested the output using result.stdout in dart and Flutter was showing the correct output.

---

Any *ideas?*

---

**Dart Code:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: tuxHomePage(),
      ),
    );

startPython() {
  Process.runSync("python3", ["myScript.py"],
      runInShell: true, workingDirectory: "/home/kq1231");
}

class tuxHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const tuxHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 50.0,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                startPython();
              },
              child: Text(
                "Go !",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white70),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Pyautogui code:**

```py
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click(x=500, y=660)
```

---

I'm expecting the script to click at (500,660) but it doesn't click. And other pyautogui functions don't seem to work as well.
If I execute the script in my linux terminal, it works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It might help if you provided code that can reproduce the problem you're observing and if you elaborated on what "does not work" means (i.e., what did you expect to observe, and what did you observe instead).

Comment: okay just a minute

Comment: what problem are u trying to solve calling pyautogui from flutter? just curious